# How to change macOS keyboard shortcuts for Word 365? (2022 / v16)

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, microsoft-word-365

I recently switched from LibreOffice to Word 365 on macOS Monterey. And instead of using Word's proprietary keyboard shortcuts, I want to change some of them to the standard ones I'm already used to from macOS in general.

Most importantly: How do I change the keyboard shortcuts in Word 365 on macOS for **moving the cursor**?

Because to do that I must enter the exact menu title for each shortcut – and of course I can't find any menu options for moving the cursor in Word 365.

So I've searched for phrases like *"Word" "Mac" "menu title" "move cursor" "keyboard shortcut"*. But nothing usable comes up.

1. Does anyone know if it's at all possible to change the Word 365 keyboard shortcuts for moving the cursor?
2. If it is, can anyone tell me what the *exact* menu titles are for each shortcut? Or direct me to a page where they are all listed?

I've tried the descriptions listed [here](https://shortcutworld.com/Word/mac/Microsoft-Word_Shortcuts) as "menu title" text for each shortcut in Word 365 in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts*. But so far nothing has happened with the four things I've tried, which is "move one paragraph up/down" and "to the beginning/end of a document".

Thanks in advance for any help or hints!

Comment: You may look at Tools -> Customize Keyboard... to remove the keybinds you want to use as moving cursors (not test on my side).

Answer (score 0):

### Have you looked at [Create a custom keyboard shortcut for Word on the Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-word-for-mac-3e865725-831c-4b45-9187-eeaf896fa110)?

> **Create a keyboard shortcut**
>
> On the `Tools` menu, select `Customize Keyboard`.
>
> In the `Categories` list, select a tab name.
>
> In the `Commands` list, select the command that you want to assign a
> keyboard shortcut to.
>
> Any keyboard shortcuts that are currently assigned to the selected
> command will appear in the Current keys box.
>
> **Tip:** If you prefer to use a different keyboard shortcut, add another
> shortcut to the list, and then use it instead.
>
> In the `Press new keyboard shortcut box`, type a key combination that
> includes at least one modifier key (`COMMAND`, `CONTROL`, `OPTION`,
> `SHIFT`) and an additional key, such as `COMMAND` + `F11` .
>
> If you type a keyboard shortcut that is already assigned, the action
> assigned to that key combination appears next to Currently
> assigned to.
>
> Select `Add`.
>
> Note: Keyboard shortcut descriptions refer to the U.S. keyboard
> layout. Keys on other keyboard layouts might not correspond to the
> keys on a U.S. keyboard. Keyboard shortcuts for laptop computers might
> also differ.